# Rails Routes Different In Development and Production

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a route working just fine in my development environment, but for some reason it's not working in production and I can't figure out why.

When I go to `http://localhost:3000/api/v1/register_panelist?api_key=ff4a6fa1c975693bedc2122e6943946b` in my development environment, it works great.

However, when I go to `http://example.com/api/v1/register_panelist?api_key=ff4a6fa1c975693bedc2122e6943946b` it does not resolve, and ends up falling to a "page not found" which is the catch all route at the bottom of my routes file.

In my `routes.rb` file I have this:

```
constraints(ApiConstraint) do

  namespace :api, defaults: {format: 'json'} do
    namespace :v1, defaults: {format: 'json'} do   

      match "register_panelist", to: "appusers#register_panelist", via: 'get'   
      match "get_surveys", to: "appusers#get_surveys", via: 'get'     

    end
  end

  match "api/v1/*path", to: "api/v1/misc#api_not_found_404", via: :all, format: 'json'
end

...
#at the very bottom
match "*path", to: "static_pages#not_found_404", via: :all, format: false #, :constraints => {:format => [:html, :png]}
```

In my development environment it seems to resolve correctly. But in production it seems to be falling through to the bottom of the `routes.rb` file.

Any ideas why?

**EDIT:** Adding Logs:

Production:

```
    production.log — I, [2017-02-12T11:55:31.455331 #27545] INFO -- : Started GET "/api/v1/register_panelist.json?api_key=ff4a6fa1c975693bedc2122e6943946b&country_id=9&birthday_year=1989&birthday_month=2&birthday_day=16&gender=42198&hispanic=42200&zip=10022&state=45700&ethnicity=42215&standard_relationship=42232&standard_education=42243&standard_hhi_us=43511" for 75.100.38.224 at 2017-02-12 11:55:31 +0000
production.log — I, [2017-02-12T11:55:31.606946 #27545] INFO -- : Prod? true
production.log — I, [2017-02-12T11:55:31.607886 #27545] INFO -- : subdomain:
production.log — I, [2017-02-12T11:55:31.607948 #27545] INFO -- : protocol: https://
production.log — I, [2017-02-12T11:55:31.608020 #27545] INFO -- : Prod? true
production.log — I, [2017-02-12T11:55:31.608052 #27545] INFO -- : subdomain:
production.log — I, [2017-02-12T11:55:31.608086 #27545] INFO -- : protocol: https://
production.log — I, [2017-02-12T11:55:31.617812 #27545] INFO -- : Processing by StaticPagesController#not_found_404 as HTML
production.log — I, [2017-02-12T11:55:31.617925 #27545] INFO -- : Parameters: {"api_key"=>"ff4a6fa1c975693bedc2122e6943946b", "country_id"=>"9", "birthday_year"=>"1989", "birthday_month"=>"2", "birthday_day"=>"16", "gender"=>"42198", "hispanic"=>"42200", "zip"=>"10022", "state"=>"45700", "ethnicity"=>"42215", "standard_relationship"=>"42232", "standard_education"=>"42243", "standard_hhi_us"=>"43511", "path"=>"api/v1/register_panelist.json"}
production.log — I, [2017-02-12T11:55:31.636463 #27545] INFO -- : Rendered text template (0.2ms)
production.log — I, [2017-02-12T11:55:31.636883 #27545] INFO -- : Completed 404 Not Found in 19ms (Views: 11.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Development:

```
Started GET "/api/v1/register_panelist?api_key=ff4a6fa1c975693bedc2122e6943946b&country_id=9&birthday_year=1989&birthday_month=2&birthday_day=16&gender=42198&hispanic=42200&zip=53593&state=45700&ethnicity=42215&standard_relationship=42232&standard_education=42243&standard_hhi_us=43511" for ::1 at 2017-02-12 05:56:46 -0600
Prod? false
subdomain: 
protocol: http://
Processing by Api::V1::AppusersController#register_panelist as JSON
  Parameters: {"api_key"=>"ff4a6fa1c975693bedc2122e6943946b", "country_id"=>"9", "birthday_year"=>"1989", "birthday_month"=>"2", "birthday_day"=>"16", "gender"=>"42198", "hispanic"=>"42200", "zip"=>"53593", "state"=>"45700", "ethnicity"=>"42215", "standard_relationship"=>"42232", "standard_education"=>"42243", "standard_hhi_us"=>"43511"}
  User Load (18.7ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."api_key" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["api_key", "ff4a6fa1c975693bedc2122e6943946b"]]
```

`rake routes` output from development:

```
api_v1_register_panelist GET    /api/v1/register_panelist(.:format)                                                           api/v1/appusers#register_panelist {:format=>"json"}
                                     api_v1_get_surveys GET    /api/v1/get_surveys(.:format)                                                                 api/v1/appusers#get_surveys {:format=>"json"}
```

and production server:

```
api_v1_register_panelist GET    /api/v1/register_panelist(.:format)                                                           api/v1/appusers#register_panelist {:format=>"json"}
                                     api_v1_get_surveys GET    /api/v1/get_surveys(.:format)                                                                 api/v1/appusers#get_surveys {:format=>"json"}
```

Comment: can you share request logs for dev & prod?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess that there is something in the web server configuration that is usurping the request before it gets passed to Rails (mod rewrite or the like), or that the mount point setting of the Rails execution environment within your web server (e.g. Unicorn in Nginx, Passenger in Apache) , or maybe a piece of middleware that is handled differently by WEBrick and your live server.

Whatever the case, I would start by checking the routes on the server:

```
rake routes
```

and make sure they are what you expect.  Next, inspect the rails logs and verify that the request is actually being handled by Rails and not being intercepted by the web server or some middleware.  If you crank log level up to debug it should give details about exactly how it is handling it.  This should at least give you the next step for where to look.

Comment: I tried turning up the log level to `:debug` and posted the production results. It actually looks to have the same amount of output as `:info` surprisingly. Any clever ideas?

Comment: @TomHammond - make sure that you restart after changing it, that you have set it in the right envirnonment and that your application is actually running in the environment that you thought it was (presumably "production").

Comment: @TomHammond - looking at the logs above, the requests are different.  the one for development is calling /api/v1/register_panelist?api_key=ff4a6f ... but the one for production is calling api/v1/register_panelist.json?api_key=ff4a....   so the format is missing in development.

As for the result below, I would definitely not leave it that way - I would find the actual problem.  Leaving the same route entered twice is going to come back to haunt you with a difficult to debug problem at 2:00 am on a Sunday.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not positive why this works, but it seems I had to update my `routes.rb` file to call out that line twice - once within the constraints to find the routes in my development environment, and once without to be found in production:

```
constraints(ApiConstraint) do

  namespace :api, defaults: {format: 'json'} do
    namespace :v1, defaults: {format: 'json'} do   

      #find in development
      match "register_panelist", to: "appusers#register_panelist", via: 'get'   
      match "get_surveys", to: "appusers#get_surveys", via: 'get'     

    end
  end

  match "api/v1/*path", to: "api/v1/misc#api_not_found_404", via: :all, format: 'json'
end

#find in production
match "api/v1/register_panelist", to: "api/v1/appusers#register_panelist", via: 'get'   
match "api/v1/get_surveys", to: "api/v1/appusers#get_surveys", via: 'get'
```

Comment: I just ran into this exact same issue. Any word on why this happens?

Comment: Not sure I ever figured it out. Glancing again at the code - the namespace seems to have the format of json in the dev one vs. not in the production one. So maybe something to do with that (even though json is still returned in the production version)... hmmm.

Comment: After digging around some more, I found this issue https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/5798, which might explain it. It seems like this issue would only apply if your namespace is an ActiveRecord model, but I doubt you have a model called `Api` or `V1`, so I'm not sure....

Comment: Nope... Do you? :)